# mock testing the return value of a dynamic function

Tags: python, mocking, unittest2

I am testing code that uses the return value of a dynamically created function.
I need to make sure that the code that I am testing correctly calls a function called 'email_invoice' with the spoofed data...

The dynamically created function hits a remote system, so I am faking the result of the call.

```py
class MyTest(unittest2.Test):

    def setUp(self):

        patcher = mock.patch('soc.product.views.API')
        patch = patcher.start()

        self.order_id = 'fake_order_id'

        # The `API` class has methods that are dynamically created.
        # The method `API.CreateOrder` needs to be patched to return `self.order_id`
        # When testing that a resulting method is called, I get a failed assertion:

        #AssertionError: Expected call: email_invoice(<User: User(id=46, merchant_id=503579)>, 'fake123123123')
        #Actual call: email_invoice(<User: User(id=46, merchant_id=503575)>, <MagicMock name='API().CreateOrder().OrderID' id='140700602174736'>)

        # soc.product.views.API.CreateOrder => self.order_id
        CreateOrderResult = mock.NonCallableMock()
        CreateOrderResult.OrderId = self.order_id
        patch.CreateOrder = mock.Mock()
        patch.CreateOrder.return_value = CreateOrderResult


    def test_that_stuff_out_homie(self):

         ... doing stuff ...

         user = ... a result of doing stuff ...

         self.patches['email_invoice'].assert_called_once_with(user, self.order_id)
```

As it mentions, the assertion fails like this:

```py
AssertionError: Expected call: email_invoice(<User: User(id=46, merchant_id=503579)>, 'fake123123123')
Actual call: email_invoice(<User: User(id=46, merchant_id=503575)>, <MagicMock name='API().CreateOrder().OrderID' id='140700602174736'>)
```

So, what is the proper/correct way to test this out?

Comment: You are assigning `self.order_id` to `OrderId` but getting the id from API by `OrderID` (notice the uppercase at the end of the string)

Comment: Add that as the answer and I can accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `self.order_id` to `OrderId` but getting the id from API by `OrderID` (notice the uppercase at the end of the string).

Comment: Yep. I figured this would be a problem because I cannot use the auto_spec functionality of patch :P

Comment: Ah, although the typo was an issue, what is happening is that the suds client is overwriting the patch when it creates the methods (or at least bypassed the patch by using a dynamic __getattr__)

Comment: You can patch that method too, or patch the function that the client is attaching to the `CreateOrder` attribute.